# How to Mock the Property File in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am creating a Unit test case using Junit . Now My application is Maven Based with many profile Also I am using the Values from configuration file (Property File ) which Varies from one profile to other. I want that Unit Test run will have specified properties only not the profile one when it is running the test cases.
These can be done in 2 ways 
1) Either i Mock the Property File for Unit Test .( which i dont know How) .
2) Or during run time i change the property file parameter values.(Again difficult to answer) . Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

One option: use **dependency injection** in order to acquire a java.util.Properties object for example.

Meaning: your production code simply holds a Properties object; like:

```
class Foo {
  private final Properties properties;

  public Foo(Properties) { 
    this.properties = properties;
```

At runtime, when the class that creates Foo objects reads property files from disk, turns them into a Properties object and gives it to the Foo constructor.

In your unit test, your test code creates a Properties object and adds whatever values you require upon creating a Foo object.

The less elegant detour: make sure that your production code reads its properties from a location that gets defined at **runtime**. That would allow you to create custom property files in some temp directory, and then  you instruct your code under test to work with those files.

Answer (score 0):

Did not got your question exactly - In one side, you are saying: you don't want to use profile related values and other side you are saying: you'll need to run with specific values (do you mean runtime values or test specific values).

Now, To answer your 1st question:
**1) Either i Mock the Property File for Unit Test:**
you can instantiate and load a property file(test specific) and keep the required values there in that file.

**2) Or during run time i change the property file parameter values:**
you can mock specific property keys with values. like below:

```
 public void shouldBuyBread() throws Exception {
    //given
    given(mypropertyUtil.getProperty("NUMBER_OF_BREADS")).willReturn(10);

    //when
    Goods goods = shop.buyBread();

    //then
    assertThat(goods, containBread());
  }
```